# Excel crash on error from afterupdate macro

Tags: excel, vba, crash, userform

I'm new to excel vba, basically using it just to create a report generator where I enter data through a userform and it generates a report.

I have two userforms in the workbook.

It was going fine until I got this "error 424 object required" from an afterupdate macro for a textbox in the second userform, and when I click on the stop button, excel crashed.

- I changed the macro to be triggered on exit of textbox, on error no crash.
- I copied the textbox with the afterupdate macro to a new userform, on error no crash.
- I copied the textbox to the first userform, on error excel crash.
- I inserted the userform am using into a new workbook, on error excel crash.

So it seems to me that there is some issue with my original two userforms..

Any thoughts on what could be the reason would be much appreciated, meanwhile I will just create two new userforms and copy the original ones into them.

Edit 1:

Here is the code that triggered the error:

```
Private Sub AKA_en_AfterUpdate()
Dim SubNo, SubNoCol As Long

SubNo = AKA.AKA_Subjects.Value 'AKA: second userform name, AKA_Subjects: Combobox with subjects number (1 to 5)
SubNoCol = (AKA.AKA_Subjects.Value * 3) + 3 'Subject no. -> Column no.

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("AKA_E" & SubNo).Value = "" 'aka_e (1 to 5) ranges where the data is populated
Dim AKA_en: AKA_en = Split(AKA.AKA_en.Value, vbCrLf) 'AKA_en: textbox
For i = 0 To UBound(AKA_en)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Cells(i + 31, SubNoCol).Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(AKA_en(i))
Next
End Sub
```

but please bare in mind that the problem is not with this code itself, it's with any error that happens in an afterupdate macro only in the two userforms i already have

Comment: If you add your code, we may be able to help you further.

Comment: Hello BigBen,I have added the code in the question now! thanks for the tip :)

Comment: I'd suggest adding the line `Option Explicit` at the top of the module[s] (if it's not already there) and try running the code again to help you identify undeclared variables, mishandled properties, etc., which could likely be part of the issue.  Also, the code you posted is in itself incomplete (see how to create a [mcve]), and if there is other relevant code (such as the AfterUpdate macros) then they should also be included.  There's more good info in [ask] and lots in [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/) from SO's top user!

Comment: Hello ashleedawg, thanks for explaining all of that, am new here and the coding world is not really mine and am only doing this cause my company doesn't want to hire someone to do it and it will help me a lot at my work..., so am gonna try my best to explain the issue.

I updated the code again, explained what is what.
The code itself like that has no problem and excel doesn't crash. It only crash when the code has a problem. Like for example if I mistakenly wrote ThisWooorkBook.Sheets" instead of thisworkbook, it creates an error. when this error happens and i click stop, excel crashes.